# Process substitution equivalent in ksh (to modify stdout)

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

I have this bash script to prepend timestamp to each entry of a log file but I am stuck at converting it into korn shell syntax.  I read korn shell doesn't like subshell. I tried to utilize function but that didn't work. In particular, I tried to convert the entire `exec` line into korn syntax. Could someone please take a look and help me?

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

exec > >(
    while read line ; do
        echo "$(date '+%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S') ${line}"
    done > n.log
) 2>&1

echo 'first line; should have an initial timestamp'
sleep 2
echo 'printed two seconds later, should have a timestamp with a comparable offset'
```

Comment: Have a look here... http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26797

Comment: Which **specific** ksh implementation? It'd be a very different answer for genuine David Korn ksh93 vs mksh or pdksh.

Comment: BTW, the bash code provided is really, **really** inefficient (`$(date)` launches a subshell, then executes an external subprocess in that subshell -- it's a whole lot of overhead to run for every single line of output). If you were using a modern (4.1? 4.2?) version of bash with native strftime support built into printf, you could vastly reduce the performance overhead of this filter.

Comment: BTW, please take everything not necessary to the immediate question out of your code. The `AA=test; export AA`, for instance, does nothing at all.

Comment: (in addition to being inefficient, it's also buggy: `while read line` trims leading and trailing whitespace and strips literal backslashes; `while IFS= read -r line` would be a better alternative).

Comment: "korn shell doesn't like subshell" just doesn't make sense -- I don't know what you mean by that, or where you would have gotten the impression from.

Comment: @Charles, Thank you for your advise. I will be using ksh93. The code is very rough right now and very inefficient. I visit this site often to search for advice and I indeed learn a lot from here. Thank you and everyone for your help.  Besides this, if I change the `exec..` code to this **exec > >(while IFS= read -r line ; do echo "`date '+%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S'` ${line}"; done > n.log) 2>&1**   What would be the best way to convert to ksh93?

Comment: @Ben, btw, to code-quote content that contains backticks, you can use triple-backticks. (But better to use `$()` -- which is specified as part of the POSIX sh standard and fully supported on ksh -- and moot the whole issue).

Answer (score 3):

The portable thing -- which will work in any POSIX-compliant shell -- is to use a named FIFO.

Here, a ksh extension (`printf %()T`) also available in recent bash is used to avoid needing to launch `date` inside the subshell.

```
mkfifo log.fifo
(while IFS= read -r line; do
   printf '%(%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S)T '
   printf '%s\n' "$line"
 done >n.log <log.fifo) &
exec >log.fifo
```

Comment: Both `bash` and `ksh` (at least the version that ships with OS X, whatever that is) can omit a second argument at all to print the current date/time.

Comment: @Charles Thank you for your help. Now it will work in both bash and ksh so I don't need two codes for different shells.

Comment: @chepner, in bash 4.4.0, `printf '%(%Y)T\n' ''` gives me `1969`. Thus, it doesn't look feasible to go that route if one wants a parameterized component in the same format string... though I suppose one could use two separate `printf` calls.

Comment: That's *an* argument, not no arugment :)

Comment: @chepner, sure -- my point being that one can't both pass no arguments and have a subsequent argument, so that restricts usage patterns. :)

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying now.

Answer (score 0):

A little expansion on Charles' excellent answer: Make it more explicit
by creating separate functions for the output modification and for the main functional code; without named pipes, there's nothing to clean up after you're done.

```
print_with_timestamps() {
  (while IFS= read -r line; do
     printf '%(%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S)T '
     printf '%s\n' "$line"
   done 
  ) > n.log 2>&1
}

main() {
echo 'first line; should have an initial timestamp'
sleep 2
echo 'printed two seconds later, should have a timestamp with a comparable offset'
}

main | print_with_timestamps
```

Comment: Works with **ksh93** but not **pdksh**.

Comment: @clintpachi the built-in printf time expansion probably does not work in pdksh, as mentioned by Charles Duffy.